# not sure about GCM implention

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My website api send a gcm notification to user in case of he received a normal texting message from another user.

Google docs explain the implention steps  like i have been coding android for 100 years, but in fact im a  nope lvl5 so i didnt understand it. 
In addition all web tutorial explain the old way, 
thus what i did is:

1-created a new app on Google console and downloaded that service.json file and add the menifest and gradle things, no errors now all good,

2-then i went to official Github gcm project and copied every thing into my project without any changes except that the Mainactivity content of Github project i added it to the login activity of my project,

still no error, but am i doing it right?.

The second question is:

when user login  i should send the user devise id to my server along with username and passowrds params,

How to get that from shered prefenince.
Soory for the long story and thanks in advance.

This is the github project 
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Comment: Please format your question. It's difficult to understand the way it is put. Just a wall of text.

Comment: Soory because not a codes problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first time when an app is launched the app registers in gcm and recieves token and it is stored in sharedpreference with a keyword. look for the gcm registering in your launching activity. then use tis key to retrive the token from sharedpreference in login activity

goto this url
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java

```
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

you have to store  value in `token` in sharedpreference

then retrieve it in login activity and send it to your server

Comment: Aha so i should add to main activity not login activity. Ok but thats all? Nothing else needed?

Comment: @SallyTaha can you post the main activity in your question

Comment: @SallyTaha:you save the value in token in RegistrationIntentService.class, I have edited my answer.

Comment: In sot this line for saving it? sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();

Comment: its only saving a boolean, whether you send data to server. are you new to programming?

Comment: Aha now i got it, yes im not expert